# Excel 2010 crashes: Excel.exe 0xc0000005 when trying to highlight from pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, conditional-formatting, dde

One of our users uses pivot tables a lot. She often called me about Excel crashing from time to time without being able to reproduce the problem. Today we have found a way to reproduce the crash every time. Here's how (Excel is in French at work, translations may be off):

1. Select three cells from the pivot table
2. Select Conditional formatting    -> Highlight rules (first one) ->
   Other rules
3. Select "Apply formatting only to first or last values" in the new
   window
4. Hit OK

Excel will stop responding. Below is the Event from the Windows Event viewer (Bing translated from French):

```
Faulting module name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4535.1507, time stamp: 0x52282c09 
exception Code: 0xc0000005 error offset: 0x00000000008104fb 
faulting process ID: 0xfb0 
faulting application start time: 0x01cec9c04bac50a7 
faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE 
faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE 
report ID: 0d6d418d-417c-11e3-9520-e0cb4e24e8d1
```

This is on my computer. I have Office 2013 64 bits with no add-ins and have been able to reproduce the same issue as hers. She has Office 2010 32 bits with some add-ins (mainly for VBA scripting and formulas).

I can't deactivate DDE since pivot tables will stop working.

The error on her PC is the same as mine.

The error will still show up with Excel in safe mode. (/s)

On both her PC and mine there is nothing checked on the compatibility tab for Excel.

This is a really weird and annoying issue, and so far I haven't been able to fix it.

Comment: Have all available Office updates been applied?

Comment: Yes, on both computers

Comment: Does this only happen with specific Excel documents, or if you make a new one with a pivot table, does it behave the same way?  Where is the Pivot Table pulling its data from?

Comment: I'll have to come back later and answer your other questions, because I need to clarify with the user and she's not at her office, but for now what I can say:

- It has happened with other files containing pivot tables (though we couldn't pinpoint the problem, so I cannot say she was doing the same operation)

- This pivot table is done using an other excel file. She sometimes use Access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742454/how-do-i-troubleshoot-this-excel-2010-crash may give you some ideas

Comment: @Pier-LucFaucher: I did that, it works for me fine in Excel 2013 (32-bit).

Comment: Have you tried using Microsoft's OffCAT tool to scan the Office installation?  It's remarkably good at finding obscure little issues that make your Office install unreliable.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2812744/office-configuration-analyzer-tool-offcat-information